# Wrong print values while iterating 2d char array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, arduino-ide

I am trying to run this code in Arduino IDE. It is printing wrong values.

```
char daysOfTheWeek[7][4] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"};

for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[i]);
    Serial.print(" ");
}

Serial.println();
```

Printed values

```
Sun Mon TuesWed Wed ThurFri Fri Sat
```

I see this can be fixed by changing the array allocation as following

```
char *daysOfTheWeek[7] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"};
```

I am fairly new to c++. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Are you familiar at all with how to use the debugger? They allow you to set a breakpoint and, when hit, you can examine the data.

Comment: `char daysOfTheWeek[7][5]` would fix it as well. You need to have enough space for the string data and a terminating 0.

Comment: @JonathanWood The piece of code seems simple to me. I have a feeling this is happening at memory level. Something like Buffer overflow but while reading. Not sure debugger can pick that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja is this expected to have an extra space for terminating 0?

Comment: I wonder why not use modern containers of C++? Like `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string`.

Comment: @HảiPhạmLê the char[] is required in my case. I am trying to print the text on a Liquid Crystal Display. The library I am using required a char[]

Comment: Just as a piece of quick information, the above code fails to compile when using Visual Studio (compiler: MSVC). This is because the max size of `const char` that can be stored in the array is `4` here (due to `[7][4]`) and `"Tues"` and `"Thur"` have 5 characters. Changing `[4]` to `[5]` worked for me and VS compiled and printed the days successfully.

Comment: @r005t3r How does the API looks like? Does it need a `char[]` and a size? I think receiving a `char[]` is like receiving a pointer, and `std::string` can also give a pointer to access to the underlying data, the difference is that underlying data is not terminated by a `\0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All string literals have an implicit null-terminator at the end. So, the biggest ones of yours, the `"Tues"` and the `"Thur"`, are actually contain **five** characters, like so: `"Tues\0"` and `"Thur\0"`.

Thus, you either need to increase the dimension of the character array to `[5]` (resulting in `char daysOfTheWeek[7][5]`), or you need to use `"Tue"` and `"Thu"` as initializers instead.

It may be graphical for you to use the fact that `Serial.print()` [returns the number of bytes written](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/), when you try to print the contents of the `daysOfTheWeek` in this way.

Meanwhile, for example, in the g++ compiler your code should give you the error: `error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long`, pointing to the two problematic string literals mentioned above.

As for the Arduino part, you may want to consider using the [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) library type.

Comment: Thanks @rawrex for the answer. daysOfTheWeek[7][5] fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the second dimension of the array is shorter than the longest word.

The code sets the second dimension up to 4. So each print statement will print up to 4 characters. The null character, which is appended to each word, counts as one. Therefore, some words like "Mon" will print correctly (3 characters for the word + 1 character for null). Longer words like "Thur" will print without the null characters, so you will see "Thur" and "Fri" back to back as in "ThurFri". To fix this situation, increase the second dimension of the array!

The second option uses pointers for which the compiler knows the length of the word automatically, and therefore, the print will be correct.

There are more ways to do this and which you can read about here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-strings-c-3-different-ways-create/